# Copy a list using a workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, external-content-type, external-list

I have an external list that pulls in info from an SQL database, I would like to create a workflow to copy the contents of the external list into a custom list

How would I do this? I can only see copy item when I create a workflow

Thanks

Comment: Are you using SPD or VS?

Comment: SharePoint designer 2013

Comment: Why do you need to copy items in the external list to a custom list?

Comment: I need to create a calendar view, an external list does not give me this functionality

Comment: Should they be able to change a value in the external list or the custom list and it should keep the other list updated?

Comment: The external list is pulling info from an external DB, information it added in the external DB not the external list or the customer list, both the external and custom list will be read only

Comment: Can anyone help me with this please, I know how to create a workflow but I am unsure what i need to put in the workflow to make it work